# How do i know if the machine is a virtual or physical

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am developing an app which runs or all physical machines and virtual machines of MAC. I want to differentiate the both. Is there any command to know what type of machine it is.

Comment: Why do you think this is important?

Comment: I want to make a record, How many virtual and how many physical